# createjs SoundJS plays mono sound instead of stereo

Tags: javascript, createjs, soundjs

I use `createjs.Sound` to play short sound for my project. I wasn't able to use `.mp3` format file and converted it to `.ogg` format. `.ogg` is playable, but sound is mono channel (I hear only in one side of headset). When I tried to play same file with VLC player, it sounds stereo channel (same file). I understood that have no problem with conversion of file and problem may be in configuration of `SoundJS`.

Can anyone advice how to configure `SoundJS` to play stereo channel audio?

Comment: Have you verified that you actually have stereo channels? Load your mp3/ogg files in something like Audacity just to verify that you have multiple channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in a version of SoundJS - maybe it's because of that (depends on the version you are using...). Check the SoundJS-Github page for further information: https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/182

You can also try to change the `pan` property: http://www.createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/AbstractSoundInstance.html#property_pan

Comment: A fix was pushed for this a while back, available in the NEXT version in GitHub. A new tagged version should be published shortly, along with new libs on the CDN. To patch this easily, just set the pan to a really low value (0.001), or set it to something, and then back to zero.